# How to make graph data in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, dataset

I am tring to make graph model (GCN). Since I am not used to PyTorch, I have a problem setting up the dataset. I want to make custom graph data.

I don't know why my code is not working properly:

```
class MoneyGraph(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        # node features
        node_features = np.loadtxt(
            "./datas/node_features.csv",
            encoding="utf-8",
            delimiter=",",
            dtype=np.float32,
            skiprows=1,
        )
        self.x = torch.tensor(node_features, dtype=torch.float)

        # label
        labels = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
        self.y = torch.tensor(labels, dtype=torch.float)

        # edge index
        target_nodes = [1, 2, 3, 5, 3, 5, 7, 1, 7]
        source_nodes = [9, 2, 2, 1, 7, 7, 3, 4, 2]
        self.edge_index = torch.tensor([source_nodes, target_nodes], dtype=torch.long)

        # etc info
        self.num_node_features = 5
        self.num_classes = 2
        self.num_nodes = len(self.x)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.x[index], self.y[index]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.x)

    def is_undirected(self):
        return False
```

And I tried to run this:

```
loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=5, shuffle=True)

for batch in loader:
    print(batch.x)
```

I get the following error message:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'x'

Answer (score 0):

Your dataset's `__getitem__` function returns a tuple of two elements. In order to access them you need to do `batch[0]`, and `batch[1]` to get the element of `self.x`, and `self.y` respectively.

Alternatively, you can destructure directly from the iterator:

```
for x, y in loader:
    print(x)
    print(y)
```

Where `x` and `y` will both have *five* elements each. The data loader handles the destructuring of batch elements for you.